# linux redirection: difference between using "2>&1" before and after "> somfilename"

Tags: zsh

What is the difference between:

```
$ ls > dirlist 2>&1
```

and

```
$ ls 2>&1 > dirlist
```

will both redirect stderr and stdout to dirlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about zsh but according to [Bash manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

```
   Note  that  the order of redirections is significant.  For example, the
   command

          ls > dirlist 2>&1

   directs both standard output and standard error to  the  file  dirlist,
   while the command

          ls 2>&1 > dirlist

   directs  only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard
   error was duplicated as standard output before the standard output  was
   redirected to dirlist.
```

---

For `ls > dirlist 2>&1`, this is what happens (in pseudo C code):

```
fd = open("dirlist");
dup2(fd, 1); // now stdout is a dup of fd so stdout points to "dirlist"
dup2(1, 2);  // now stderr becomes a dup of stdout so it also points to "dirlist"
```

For `ls 2>&1 > dirlist`, this is what happens:

```
             // initially, both stdout and stderr point to the tty
dup2(1, 2);  // now stderr becomes a dup of stdout so they still point to the tty

fd = open("dirlist");
dup2(fd, 1); // now stdout is a dup of fd so stdout points to "dirlist",
             // but stderr still points to tty
```

Comment: `directs both standard output and standard error to  the  file  dirlist` how you say that. How to understand the sequence of execution

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi `ls > dirlist 2>&1` first sets file descriptor 1 to point to `dirlist` instead of `stdout`.  Then it points the file descriptor 2 to where file descriptor 1 is pointing instead of `stderr`, which is now `dirlist`.  `ls 2>&1 > dirlist` first sets file descriptor 2 to where file descriptor 1 is pointing, which is `stdout`, and then points file descriptor 1 to point to `dirlist`, so now errors go to `stdout` and regular output goes to `dirlist`.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi -- take a look at syscall [dup2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) for how fd duplication works.

Comment: Sorry i am new to dup2. In the second logic `2 is pointing to 1 (which is stdout)`. but ultimately `1 is pointing to dirlist`. So `2 outputs should also go to  to dirlist instead of stdout`  since all `stdout is going to dirlist`. I am imagining them like some physical pipes. `2 is connected to 1 and 1 is connected dirlist`

Comment: updated by adding pseudo C code and explanations. hope that helps.

Comment: @pynexj : Zsh behaves in the respect like bash.

Answer (score 4):

Shell redirection/pipe operators are applied in the order they occur on the command line. Once you know that and read the operators the correct way, the difference becomes clear, so let's look at the operators in a little more detail:

- FD is short for file descriptor, a number that is associated with a file(-like object) on a per-process basis. File descriptors 0 through 2 have special meanings: they are the standard input/output/error streams. If you run a program in your shell without any redirection operators, they are essentially connected to your terminal.
- Redirecting `a` to `b` means: make the FD for `a` refer to the same thing as `b`, i.e. after redirection, the two file descriptors can be used interchangeably (the old `a` is lost). Internally this happens using the `dup2` syscall.
- `>foo` replaces `stdout` with a handle that writes to `foo`
- `2>&1` replaces FD 2 (`stderr`) with a handle that writes to what FD 1 (`stdout`) refers to *at that moment*.

With that in mind, here's what happens for the two variants:

`>foo 2>&1`: the shell opens a new FD that writes into `foo`, and redirects `stdout` to it, meaning FD 1 now writes into `foo`. Then, this FD 1 is duplicated into FD 2, implicitly closing the old FD 2 (which was referring to the original `stderr`). As a result, both FDs write into `foo`.

`2>&1 >foo`: the shell first duplicates FD 1 into FD 2, so that errors get written to `stdout`. Then, it creates a new FD that writes to `foo` and duplicates it into FD 1. Due to the order of redirection operators, this overwrites FD 1 but FD 2 still refers to the "old" FD 1. As a result, FD 2 writes to the old `stdout` (probably your terminal) and FD 1 writes to `foo` which replaced the old `stdout`.